# How were some gods brought back to life?

Tags: plot-explanation, gods-of-egypt

In Gods of Egypt, lots of gods have been killed during the movie, and it was mentioned more than once that this is impossible to bring back the dead, including dead gods.

However, in the end, some gods who have been killed, are back and alive.

> e.g. Thoth, god of Wisdom whose brain was taken away.

How is this possible? I didn't notice anything explaining it in the movie itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible since Ra has the ability to create life he recreated him. The only thing I can tell to refute this is that when Bek died and was lain beside Zaya, Ra brought them back without their corpses being made anew, just reanimated. It is also very possible (and even more likely) Ra had the power all along and decided to play fairy God mother to Horus granting him his wish for completing his task.